# JQuery isn't recognizing background color of #FFFFFF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a quick thingy where the web page changes color every time you click a button. I've written JS which will change the bg color to red if the current bg is #FFFFFF. After it didn't work with the default, I tried explicitly setting the bg color through CSS and HTML script tag to #FFFFFF. Neither worked. Oddly, the JS runs if I change the == operator to !==.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        if ($("body").attr("background-color") == "#FFFFFF") {
          $("body").css("background-color", "red");
        } else if ($("body").attr("background-color") == "red") {

        };
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
  <button>hi</button>
  <div class="test">text</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for a background-color attribute on the body. Body doesn't have a background-color attribute. It has a style attribute - which in turn has a background-color attribute.

Option 1: Change your if statement to check for the style:

```
if ($("body").attr("style") == "background-color: #FFFFFF;")
```

- This will only work if you don't add additional styles. You are better off using Option 2 below.

Option 2: Set the color via a css class, then check whether the body has that class.

```
CSS:
.white { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
.red { background-color: red; }

JQUERY:
if ($("body").hasClass("white")) {
    $("body").removeClass("white").addClass("red");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was just about to give up on this. Learned a lot from the answer, too!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `attr` to retrieve a style property, you have to `css` instead :
`$("body").css("background-color")`

more informations here : https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: added the same moment =)

Comment: I replaced instances of attr with css and it still isn't running, though the !== replacement still oddly works. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can add a `console.log($("body").css("background-color"))` at the begining of your click handler and open the console to see whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not attribute, it is style that you checking. Attributes are inside tags, styles are inside css. Use `$("body").css("background-color")`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $("body").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
```